# Quarkus cannot find valid Docker environment for databases

Tags: java, quarkus

When I put quarkus.datasource.db-kind to either derby or h2, quarkusDev runs fine.

However, when I try putting quarkus.datasource.db-kind to db2 (tried postgresql with the same result) I get the following error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a valid Docker Environment.

I'm assuming that quarkus is trying to fetch a docker container for starting the database, but cannot find it. It does occurs a bit strange to be that quarkus is trying to start a database in quarkusDev-mode, but anyways.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Error:

```
    2021-06-23 10:59:21,159 ERROR [io.qua.dep.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain] (main) Failed to start quarkus: java.lang.RuntimeException: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
        [error]: Build step io.quarkus.datasource.deployment.devservices.DevServicesDatasourceProcessor#launchDatabases threw an exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please see logs and check configuration
        at org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy.lambda$getFirstValidStrategy$7(DockerClientProviderStrategy.java:215)
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:408)
        at org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy.getFirstValidStrategy(DockerClientProviderStrategy.java:207)
        at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.getOrInitializeStrategy(DockerClientFactory.java:136)
        at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.client(DockerClientFactory.java:178)
        at org.testcontainers.LazyDockerClient.getDockerClient(LazyDockerClient.java:14)
        at org.testcontainers.LazyDockerClient.authConfig(LazyDockerClient.java:12)
        at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:310)
        at io.quarkus.devservices.db2.deployment.DB2DevServicesProcessor$1.startDatabase(DB2DevServicesProcessor.java:31)
        at io.quarkus.datasource.deployment.devservices.DevServicesDatasourceProcessor.startDevDb(DevServicesDatasourceProcessor.java:217)
        at io.quarkus.datasource.deployment.devservices.DevServicesDatasourceProcessor.launchDatabases(DevServicesDatasourceProcessor.java:103)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$2.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:920)
        at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:277)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2415)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1452)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)

        at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.runAugment(AugmentActionImpl.java:396)
        at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.createInitialRuntimeApplication(AugmentActionImpl.java:269)
        at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.createInitialRuntimeApplication(AugmentActionImpl.java:66)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.firstStart(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:79)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.accept(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:378)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.accept(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:56)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.app.CuratedApplication.runInCl(CuratedApplication.java:127)
        at io.quarkus.bootstrap.app.CuratedApplication.runInAugmentClassLoader(CuratedApplication.java:84)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeMain.start(DevModeMain.java:144)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeMain.main(DevModeMain.java:63)
Caused by: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
        [error]: Build step io.quarkus.datasource.deployment.devservices.DevServicesDatasourceProcessor#launchDatabases threw an exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please see logs and check configuration
        at org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy.lambda$getFirstValidStrategy$7(DockerClientProviderStrategy.java:215)
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:408)
        at org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy.getFirstValidStrategy(DockerClientProviderStrategy.java:207)
        at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.getOrInitializeStrategy(DockerClientFactory.java:136)
        at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.client(DockerClientFactory.java:178)
        at org.testcontainers.LazyDockerClient.getDockerClient(LazyDockerClient.java:14)
        at org.testcontainers.LazyDockerClient.authConfig(LazyDockerClient.java:12)
        at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:310)
        at io.quarkus.devservices.db2.deployment.DB2DevServicesProcessor$1.startDatabase(DB2DevServicesProcessor.java:31)
        at io.quarkus.datasource.deployment.devservices.DevServicesDatasourceProcessor.startDevDb(DevServicesDatasourceProcessor.java:217)
        at io.quarkus.datasource.deployment.devservices.DevServicesDatasourceProcessor.launchDatabases(DevServicesDatasourceProcessor.java:103)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$2.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:920)
        at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:277)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2415)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1452)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)

        at io.quarkus.builder.Execution.run(Execution.java:116)
        at io.quarkus.builder.BuildExecutionBuilder.execute(BuildExecutionBuilder.java:79)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.QuarkusAugmentor.run(QuarkusAugmentor.java:153)
        at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.runAugment(AugmentActionImpl.java:394)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please see logs and check configuration
        at org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy.lambda$getFirstValidStrategy$7(DockerClientProviderStrategy.java:215)
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:408)
        at org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy.getFirstValidStrategy(DockerClientProviderStrategy.java:207)
        at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.getOrInitializeStrategy(DockerClientFactory.java:136)
        at org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory.client(DockerClientFactory.java:178)
        at org.testcontainers.LazyDockerClient.getDockerClient(LazyDockerClient.java:14)
        at org.testcontainers.LazyDockerClient.authConfig(LazyDockerClient.java:12)
        at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:310)
        at io.quarkus.devservices.db2.deployment.DB2DevServicesProcessor$1.startDatabase(DB2DevServicesProcessor.java:31)
        at io.quarkus.datasource.deployment.devservices.DevServicesDatasourceProcessor.startDevDb(DevServicesDatasourceProcessor.java:217)
        at io.quarkus.datasource.deployment.devservices.DevServicesDatasourceProcessor.launchDatabases(DevServicesDatasourceProcessor.java:103)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$2.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:920)
        at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:277)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2415)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1452)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)
```

applications.properties (located in main)

```
quarkus.datasource.db-kind = db2

quarkus.datasource.username = testdb
quarkus.datasource.password = testdb

quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation = update
```

gradle.properties:

```
#Gradle properties
#Wed Jun 23 10:41:16 CEST 2021
quarkusPluginVersion=1.13.2.Final
quarkusPlatformArtifactId=quarkus-universe-bom
quarkusPluginId=io.quarkus
quarkusPlatformGroupId=io.quarkus
//\#=-*- coding\: utf-8 -*-
systemProp.org.gradle.internal.publish.checksums.insecure=true
org.gradle.logging.level=INFO
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m
version=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
quarkusPlatformVersion=1.13.2.Final
```

Comment: The problem happens when you use h2? That is weird...

Comment: @geoand I think it's the other way round, quoting "_When I put quarkus.datasource.db-kind to either derby or **h2**, quarkusDev **runs fine**_".

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos Exactly.

Comment: From the stack trace it seems that there is something wrong with your TestContainers configuration (?) maybe look for `@QuarkusTestResource` in your code (?)

Comment: OK, so basically when you use `quarkus.datasource.db-kind=postgresql` and you don't set `quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url` you get the behavior you mention, correct?

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos
I don't annotated with QuarkusTestResource. I do however split my tests into different testing profiles. But the test configs shouldn't mess with quarkusDev, right?

Comment: @geoand
Correct. Is it required to set an url?

Answer (score 11):

What you are seeing is Quarkus attempting to launch a container to run the database because you have not specified a `quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url`.
This feature is called DevServices and you find more information about it [here](https://quarkus.io/guides/datasource#devservices-configuration-free-databases).

This feature essentially kicks in in dev and test modes when you have not specified the database to be used.

You can explicitly run it off using `quarkus.datasource.devservices.enabled=false` or by setting `quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url` to a URL of a running database

Comment: Great info geoand :)

Comment: Glad it's useful :)

Comment: Awesome! The problem for me is that quarkusDev requires a docker runtime app installed in order to start the Testcontainer, according to this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=szza3DZlKzA&t=166s

I'll just have to find a way to start up a local database and then connect to that one via the quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error because Docker Desktop was not started after I restarted my machine ... Maybe this info will help someone in the future!